# Getting Exception while implementing RowLevelSecurity

Tags: broadleaf-commerce

I am Trying to Implement `RowLevelSecurity`, For Restrict Admin User According to Storage. I have Followed this URL
**

> http://www.broadleafcommerce.com/docs/core/current/broadleaf-concepts/admin/admin-row-level-security.

**
And I had override these methods :
`addFetchRestrictions()` and `addFetchRestrictionsRoot()` .

So when I logged In in Admin Application, I can access all the link except product link when I clicked on Product link then I am Getting `ClassCastException` like This:

> "java.lang.ClassCastException:
>   org.broadleafcommerce.openadmin.server.security.domain.AdminUserImpl
>   cannot be cast to com.iwn.admin.user.MyAdminUser"

When I debug my application I get to know that I am getting Exception in following lines:

```
Store adminStore = ((MyAdminuser) currentUser).getStore();
```

Can anyone help me that how to resolve this issue, Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you have extended `AdminuserImpl` to your custom `MyAdminuser` make sure that you have followed all the instructions in http://www.broadleafcommerce.com/docs/core/current/tutorials/core-tutorials/extending-entities-tutorial.

If you have done that but are still relying on the initial data imports, your data is likely wrong. Assuming that you have a table called `MY_ADMIN_USER` (that maps to the MyAdminuser Hibernate object), make sure that you have entries in that table for all of the entries in BLC_ADMIN_USER. Otherwise, Hibernate can only give you back instances of `AdminUserImpl` instead of your extended `MyAdminuser`.

One easy way to ensure this is with this SQL query:

`INSERT INTO MY_ADMIN_USER (ADMIN_USER_ID) (SELECT blc.ADMIN_USER_ID FROM BLC_ADMIN_USER AS blc);`